# Using central & peripheral in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am new to ios. i have a requirement to use BLE in ios.I have gone through the apple official documentation of apple for core bluetooth framework [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH1-SW1)

They have talked about central & peripheral i have an app in which user will search for near by BLE devices ,select device,make connection, enter some data through text box,switch,drop down menu and send all data to another connected BLE device.

So i am confused which role my app is going to play central as well as peripheral?? 
I think the both??

if both then do i need to set the services & characteristics of that devices or the vendor of that device has already have done for me?

Comment: It sounds like you will be a central - you will discover the peripheral.  The peripheral will have services and characteristics defined

Comment: But it is written in apple docs that peripheral provides data but in my case i have some data & sending to another device.

Comment: No, the peripheral defines the services and characteristics. Data can be read from and written to characteristics. The central discovers and connects to peripherals.

Comment: Actually the device on which i want to write the data is not a iOS device.So it means that device has already defined some services & characteristics i only have to search it,connect it & write down it's service's characteristic.Right ?

Comment: Correct, although hopefully the manufacturer has documented this for you (or is using a standard profile)

Comment: Oh really so that would be easy for me. and what about the pairing with device when i pair it should display code for authentication ?

Comment: You only pair with BLE when encryption is in use - defined by the peripheral. If pairing is require the iOS will display a pairing dialogue. Regardless of whether pairing is required you need to write the UI to discover devices and select the one to connect to.

Comment: hmmm. So it means the vendor has not defined the services on the device there will be no pairing pairing dialog?

Comment: If the vendor has not flagged any of their characteristics as "encryption required" then there will be no pairing initiated as there is no need for key exchange

Comment: Ok.. Thank you very very much.Where i can more about the knowledge you shared if you could provide me the ref as links,pdf. please if you can provide me your contact info

Comment: The CoreBluetooth Programming Guide that you linked to is what I used.

Comment: What if i have to read all the data which i sent to the device i have read the data which last time i sent to device.In that case i guess device will act as a peripheral & it will provide me some data from where i can read the data.

Comment: I would like to ask what type of data will be sent to that non ios device like i have text filed in my app, i enter some value say 10 & send it to non ios BLE device so in that case do i need to convert that data into some sort of format like biinary of something??

Comment: It depends on the peripheral and the service/characteristics.

Comment: what about the type of data sent to the device ?

Comment: As I said, it depends on the device

Comment: oh sorry i thought you answered my previous question. Ok i have gone through some of the examples they are using NSData to write the data.

Comment: Does the Bluetooth framework in case the connection is lost or device is not reachable?

Comment: You will receive a disconnect notification and you can issue a new connection request.  This is all covered in the programming guide.

Comment: one last thing i ask i have done lot R&D over enabling the ios device bluetooth programmatically & i have come to know that we can't do this by using the public API there some Private API by which we can accomplish this task. Is it really true or is there any other way around?

Comment: No, if the user has turned Bluetooth off, all you can do is display a dialog requesting that they turn it on.  They may have turned it off for a valid reason - flight mode or to save battery

Comment: Thank you very much you don't know how much you have helped by providing solutions.How can i reach you if i have to ask again or comes out with some more questions?

Comment: Just ask a question on this site.

Comment: Ok i'll use same tags i hope i find you.

Comment: for accessing services & discovering devices we need to provide the servic UUID so will that id given by vendor. i guess i am right ?

Comment: @Paulw11 hello, i was expecting an answer ?

Comment: I think the original question has been addressed.  If you have further questions then you should ask another question, however if I understand what you are asking then you can either scan for all devices or you can specify a service to scan for - this is more efficient if you know the service you are interested in

Comment: please see my question i have asked a new question ? @Paulw11